# Type Casting in c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with declaring a **type** as passed from parameter type variable.

```
public static void ShowThisForm(Type passXtraForm, Form parent)
    {
        var xfrm = passXtraForm.GetType();
        xfrm xfrmName = new xfrm();
        xfrmName.Show();
    }
```

Can I declare a variable as a type from passXtraForm.GetType() and declare it to another variable? Just passing the type of form to another class.

Thanks in advance for the response.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to make it clearer?

Comment: Use generics, that's what they are for.

Comment: If you are passing a type, you might as well pass an object and use reflection to determine what to do with the object.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: I think that he wants to pass in a type as a method parameter and then create an instance of that type.

Comment: this is how i used it.. ShowThisForm(typeOf(frmMain), this); in the method, i dont know what is the type of passXtraForm, is it frmMain or another forms.. so i need to create an instance of that type.. :)

Comment: Unfortunately `Type` isn't the same as `class` and classes aren't first class objects in C# so this won't work, but fortunately there are generics which covers 90% of the times where you'd want to work with a class object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't look like you need the `parent` parameter; I'd eliminate it entirely. Then I'd use generics to do what you're trying to accomplish:

```
public static void ShowThisForm<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    T xfrmName = new T();
    xfrmName.Show();
}
```

The `where T : Form, new()` portion of this code is called a **type constraint** and it prevents you from calling the `ShowThisForm` method with a type that doesn't have a default constructor and derive from `Form`.

By indicating that `T` must have a default constructor, the compiler knows how to resolve `new T()`; by indicating that `T` derives from `Form`, the compiler knows how to call the `.Show()` method.

So, if you have a form class called `MyForm`, you could use the following syntax to call this method:

```
ShowThisForm<MyForm>();
```

For more documentation, you should take a look at these articles on MSDN:

- [Generic Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: thanks sir and thanks for the responds.. got the answer from this code.. ;)

Comment: @vrynxzent No problem. I'd encourage you to read the MSDN pages, generics are a powerful concept and can be used to write more flexible /reusable code.

Answer (score 4):

you could use generics for this:

```
public static void ShowThisForm<T>(T passXtraForm, Form parent) where T : Form, new()
{
     T xfrmName = new T();
     xfrmName.Show();
}
```

in this case the type argument is restricted to the Form type and types deriving from Form.
anyway, *why* are you having this method? there are other methods in the Form and Application static classes for finding the forms out there in your app...

Comment: Just what I was about to type. Although I think the first parameter can be omitted and you need an extra constraint on the T: `new()`

Comment: What about "new" constraint? This won't compile :D

Comment: that's what you get for writing it down here and not using an editor, thanks for the tip I updated the answer, and the parameters stay for sake of clarity (looks like the original)

Answer (score 1):

You could change it to something more like this:

```
    public static void ShowThisForm<T>() where T : Form, new()
    {
        T xfrmName = new T();
        xfrmName.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe pass in [a factory](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory), so that a known interface can instantiate what ever type of object the calling code deems is necessary?

(the below code is a quick sample I typed in here; formatting is off, and design could be better. It's just to give an idea)

```
static class XFactory
{

  private int _id;

   public XFactory(int formId) {
      _id = formId;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Decides which class to instantiate.
   /// </summary>
   public static Form Get()
   {
     switch (_id)
     {
    case 0:
        return new FormA();
    case 1:
    case 2:
        return new FormB();
    case 3:
    default:
        return new FromC();
     }
   }
}


public static void Main()
{

  ShowThisForm(new XFactory(2));

}

public static void ShowThisForm(XFactory formFactory)
    {
        var xfrm = formFactory.Get();
        xfrm.Show();
    }
```

Comment: This is overkill, if we're talking about something that inherits from a common interface, like a WinForm. heh.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a class/type via reflection and Activator.CreateInstance(typ, constructorargs), but most likely it would be better to create the object elsewhere and have it be of either a known base class (in your case it looks like form), or have it implement a defined interface that can be used to manipulate it.  Very rarely will you need to create an object of totally unknown type.